# ¿Cómo puedo centrar un texto en el encabezado completo sin tomar en cuenta el espacio del botón con CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando en un encabezado `HTML` y `CSS` en el que quiero centrar el título en todo el encabezado, en lugar de que se centre solo en el espacio sobrante después del botón. Mi código actual se ve así:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #dee1e6;
  height: 7%;
  font-size: 21px;
}

#boton {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.titulo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="boton">Botón</div>
  <div class="titulo">Encabezado</div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr que el título se centre en todo el encabezado (es decir, en el total de la caja `.header`)?

¡De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, los elementos ocupan un espacio que no puede ser ocupado por otros elementos, pero podemos alterar dicho comportamiento.

En tu caso, necesitarías que el botón no ocupase ese espacio por defecto, para que de esa manera el título pudiese ocupar el 100% del ancho del padre, quedando de esta manera centrado respecto a este.

Para ello he usado `position: relative` para el `header` y `position: absolute` para el botón.

La regla `position: absolute` saca del flujo normal de la página al elemento, y su posicionamiento pasa a ser relativo al primer ancestro con posicionamiento relativo que encuentre (por eso el darle dicho posicionamiento al header, para que aunque no ocupe espacio si que queda encuadrado dentro de los límites que permite el header).

Lo único que tendrías que controlar es que es que el título no acabe pisando al botón cuando el layout se reduce a cierto tamaño de dispositivo. Para ello puedes servirte de un `@media` para hacer la fuente del título más pequeña o algún arreglo similar.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #dee1e6;
  height: 7%;
  font-size: 21px;
  position: relative;
}

#boton {
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.titulo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="boton">Botón</div>
  <div class="titulo">Encabezado</div>
</div>
```